# cdkDropListDropped event not emitted when item is dropped

Tags: angular-material, angular-cdk-drag-drop

I am trying to do drag and drop without deleting the item from the dragged list. I followed an example [Working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d6xsgx) and tried to reproduce the same. Unfortunately it was not working and I found that the cdkDropListDropped event is emitted. You can find the issue in this link [Problematic demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-69hbzg)

I want to achieve like the [Working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d6xsgx)

Please show me where I am wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found I had to move the directives `cdkDropList` and `cdkDropListConnectedTo="drop-list"` from the div with ID `div1` to the parent div so the HTML becomes:

```
<div class="column left" cdkDropList cdkDropListConnectedTo="drop-list">
    <div id="div1" cdkDrag  *ngFor="let type of types" [cdkDragData]="type" (cdkDragMoved)="moved($event)" (cdkDropListDropped)="itemDropped($event)">
        {{type.text}}
        <div *cdkDragPlaceholder class="field-placeholder"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

At this point the `cdkDropListDropped` event fired and called the `itemDropped` function. The problem then was, there was a runtime error on the following line:

```
copyArrayItem(
     event.previousContainer.data,
     event.container.data,
     event.previousIndex,
     event.currentIndex
);
```

After copying the `itemDropped` method from your working demo StackBlitz, it then started work. Please see [this StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-orfwn1?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcopy-drag-drop%2Fcopy-drag-drop.component.ts) for a demo.